# Cant get localstorage to work

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, local-storage, line-breaks

I am trying to store text from textarea with localstorage. 
It works just fine, but when i insert line breake it does nothing.

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="text" id="contact_text" class="inputbox required"></textarea>

<script>
document.getElementById("contact_text").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("kommentaar");
var that = "<?php $text = JRequest::getVar('text'); echo $text; ?>";
localStorage.setItem('kommentaar',that);
</script>
```

Example: When "Hello, world!" is entered to textarea and the script is runned it works, but when

"Hello,
world!"

is entered it doesn't work...

What am i doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

There is no matter with and without line break for getting text from textarea. Because this below example is running with both conditions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="text" id="contact_text" class="inputbox required"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="saveValue()"  value="save value"/>
<script>
function saveValue(){
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
        var value = document.getElementById('contact_text').value;
        localStorage.setItem('val', value);
        alert(localStorage.getItem('val'));
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Perhaps your problem is in this statement `var that = "<?php $text = JRequest::getVar('text'); echo $text; ?>";`